# how to escape quotes inside onclick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have the following markup and i can't escape the ajax part of the onclick event,it is content append dynamically.

```
    <a class="_button" onclick="$('#add ul')
.append('<li><div class=\'error\'>
<img src=\'img/spinner.gif\' class=\'ajax_progress\' /><span></span></div></div>
<b class=\'bg\'>Prénom, Nom</b> <input type=\'text\'  onclick=\'$(this).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);\' 
class=\'_input _input_text\' style=\'width: 200px;height:24px\' value=\'\' /> 
<b class=\'bg\'>Montant</b> 
<input type=\'text\' id=\'\' 
class=\'_input _input_text _int\' 
style=\'height:24px\' value=\'\' /> € 
<input type=\'submit\' class=\'_submit\' cs_user_id=\'\'  
onclick=\'$.ajax({type:\'POST\',url:\'\'})\'  
value=\'Ajouter\'  /></li>')" 
style="float: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 5px;">Ajouter un associé</a>
```

the part that returns an error is this one:

```
onclick=\'$.ajax({type:\'POST\',url:\'\'})\'


syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

$.ajax({type:
```

so i guess it is because i have single quotes inside single quotes,but is there a way to escape quotes in this case?

Comment: Have you tried a double back slash or replacing the onClick quotes with double quotes

Comment: double backslash won't work, however the doublequotes will. escaping quotes with backslash doesn't work in attribute values.

Comment: Single quote is invalid JSON as @KevinB mentioned try double quotes. And why so much of mess in inline JavaScript!

Answer (score 3):

Holy cow that's hard to read.  Don't do this to yourself.  Create a separate JS file and just add this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").on('click', function () {
   $.ajax({type: "POST", url: ""});
});
```

In another JS file you can use all the quotes you want.

Comment: i have tried that but i need to grab an attribute (cs_user_id) that is dynamically created with jquery ui autocomplete.

Comment: @user7832 so why can't you do that?

Comment: i've just tried , the function does not see my dynamically created markup, this is why i'm trying with inline functions

Comment: @user7832 which dynamically created markup?  Why can't you just use `$(this).attr('cs_user_id')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to add a bunch of these LI's dynamically, you probably want to add an event listener to the document that will handle all of the click events on a particular selector.  Here's an example you might try:

```
$(document).on("click", "._input ._input_text", function(e) {$(e.target).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);});
```

This will need to go inside your DOM ready function, and it will automatically add the click event handler to objects that match the selector.